# Check Access points

Tags: android

I need to know how could I find if there are any access points available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`WifiManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) system manager from your activity's context:

```
(WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

[`startScan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#startScan%28%29) kicks off a new scan; when it finishes the system broadcasts an intent for [`SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION). You can then call [`getScanResults`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getScanResults%28%29) to get the list of [`ScanResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html) objects, including SSIDs, frequencies, etc. Google around for examples, like [this one](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/40.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Connectivity Manager:

Include following permission to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE">
```

Heres a sample code:

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityMgr=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] networkInfo=connectivityMgr.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for(NetworkInfo network:networkInfo){

        if(network.getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED||
                network.getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING){
            return true;
        }
        else 
            return false;
    }
```